# Auto completion in cakePHP stopped working - Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, cakephp-2.1, eclipse-pdt

After upgrading Eclipse the auto-completion feature doesn't work anymore. It still does show the regular PHP functions but not the framework specific ones (I use cakePHP) There are no errors in the project. I've tried removing the project and adding it up again but doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DLTK needs to be re-indexed. Follow the following steps:

- Close Eclipse
- Go to your workspace and remove the contents in `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2/`
- Start Eclipse again. In the beginning you see Eclipse is building up the DLTK index.

Source: 2 hours of searching throughout the internet with multiple se's